# Importing from Git to Eclipse changes project structure in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, git, maven, selenium

When I import a project from Github (I tried copying URL and Zip download) to Eclipse (tried Open from the file system, Git clone URI, Import>existing Maven project), the structure of the project changes in Eclipse. I am able to push/pull to the same Git repo using the existing local project I have in my Eclipse workspace. When I try importing to a new workspaceor to my colleague's Eclipse, this issue happens.

[Correct structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rgf8o.jpg)
[Incorrect structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c3KDd.jpg)

Comment: This is because on second machine , the maven won't able to download all the dependencies correctly . Go to users and delete .m2 folder . Go to eclipse and click on project - select maven -> update project. Wait until all dependencies gets downloaded